# Data frame column not in the index

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to calculate the mean, standard deviation, and variance in a data frame.
My initial file has a lot of information about measures on a location, so I am trying to create another data frame for a specific location. Then if I use `describe()` it works fine, and I am getting all the indicators as shown below:

[image: descibe dataframe]

When I check all the columns of the data frame with `head()` I am getting the following results:

[image: dataframe head]

What is strange is when I am trying to calculate the measures for a specific column, if I do not use reindex, I receive a message warning about that column not being in the Index.
If I do the reindex, the measures for that column are appearing as `NaN` as shown below:

[image: data frame in reindex]

So why is it that my column `RADON` is not in the index if it is present and I am able to use `describe`?
And why when I use reindex the measures are `NaN`? Does it mean that my values are not numerical?

Comment: What do `describe` and `head` show after the `reindex`?

Comment: after reindex describe show NaN for the radon value, but all the other columns are ok.